# Using sessions with perl Dancer/plack/Starman and multiple workers

Tags: perl, session, dancer, plack, starman

I'm running a perl Dancer application using Starman via plack (hopefully that is describing things correctly), and mostly this has been a painless experience.  I've just recently been trying to get sessions working (*really* simple stuff - I just want to store a couple of strings, and I am using session: "Simple"), and I am running into really strange issues when running Starman with multiple workers.

Using the following very simple code (at the bottom) results in the following:

Standalone app:
Works fine - counter increments when you click on it.

Starman - 1 worker:
Works fine

Starman - 2+ workers:
The session appears to exist for approximately 1 second, and is subsequently destroyed - the counter always "expires" after a very very short period of time.  It doesn't appear to be a worker-specific session, it just resets to nothing.  If you hammer the link more than once a second, it increments normally forever (or for as long as I could be bothered to test it).

Am I doing anything wrong, or is this just not going to work?  It isn't terribly critical, but it would be nice to be able to get simple sessions working.

Thanks,

Dave

```
##
## Code to reproduce via:
## plackup -D -E env -s Starman --workers=3 -p 3000 -a myapp.pl
##

get '/sessiontest' => sub {
    return(&sessiontest());
};

sub sessiontest {
  my $testcounter = session 'testcounter' || 0;
  $testcounter++;
  session 'testcounter' => $testcounter;
  info "SESSION COUNTER($testcounter)";
  my $return = <<EOF;
<html>
<body>
<a href=\"/sessiontest\">$testcounter</a>
</body>
</html>
EOF
  return($return);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like 
[docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Dancer/lib/Dancer/Session/Simple.pm#DESCRIPTION) say:

> This module implements a very simple session backend, holding all
>   session data in memory. This means that sessions are volatile, and no
>   longer exist when the process exits. This module is likely to be most
>   useful for testing purposes.

I think that two different workers don't share session information, because they both have their own copy in memory.

**EDIT**

Seems I was too enthusiastic with hammering. When I made bigger pause between request, session info vanished, indeed.

Comment: If that were the case, I would expect to (randomly?) switch between the workers, and get different counters.  This isn't what is happening though - the session appears to be getting destroyed (and thus getting reset to 0) - you either get nothing, or the value you are expecting, regardless of thread count, which isn't consistent with switching between in-memory values owned by each worker.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, I just retested using session: "YAML" and it looks like it works fine - it is just Simple that seems to be having issues.  I'm going to go ahead and use that for the time being, but I would still be curious to receive an answer if anyone has any insight.

Dave